# Usar Web Service para enviar datos entre página web y aplicación de escritorio vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webservice

Estoy haciendo un web service que me permita enviar información entre dos aplicaciones, una es una página web en asp.net y la otra una aplicación de escritorio den vb.net

Solo sé (gracias a ejemplos en la web de microsoft) crear funciones que me retornan datos según lo que quiera hacer, por ejemplo:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Function FahrenheitToCelsius(ByVal Fahrenheit As Double) _
        As Double
        Return ((Fahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9
    End Function
```

Conversiones entre datos y esas cosas...

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Function CelsiusToFahrenheit(ByVal Celsius As Double) _
            As Double
        Return ((Celsius * 9) / 5) + 32
    End Function
```

Sé hacer el envío de datos mediante sockets, pero ahora quiero hacer lo mismo pero usando un web service

Por ejemplo, aquí uso sockets para recibir los datos de una consulta

```
Public Function RecibirSocket()
        Dim flag As String = ""
        ' Create an instance of the TcpListener class.
        Dim output As String = ""
        Dim tcpListener As TcpListener = Nothing
        Dim ipAddress As IPAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList(0)
        Try
            ' Set the listener on the local IP address.
            ' and specify the port.
            tcpListener = New TcpListener(ipAddress, 60000)
            tcpListener.Start()
            output = "Waiting for a connection..."
        Catch e As Exception
            output = "Error: " + e.ToString()
            MessageBox.Show(output)
        End Try
        While flag <> "Ok"
            ' Always use a Sleep call in a while(true) loop
            ' to avoid locking up your CPU.
            'Thread.Sleep(10)
            ' Create a TCP socket.
            ' If you ran this server on the desktop, you could use
            ' Socket socket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket()
            ' for greater flexibility.
            Dim tcpClient As TcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient()
            ' Read the data stream from the client.
            Dim bytes(1800) As Byte
            Dim stream As NetworkStream = tcpClient.GetStream()
            stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
            processMsg(tcpClient, stream, bytes)
            tcpListener.Stop()
            flag = "Ok"
        End While
        Return flag
    End Function
```

El otro método que llamo

```
    Private mscClient As TcpClient = Nothing
    Private mstrMessage As Byte() = Nothing
    Private mstrResponse As String = Nothing
    Private bytesSent() As Byte = Nothing

Public Sub processMsg(ByVal client As TcpClient, ByVal stream As NetworkStream, ByVal bytesReceived() As Byte)
        ' Handle the message received and 
        ' send a response back to the client.
        Try
            mstrMessage = (bytesReceived)
            mscClient = client
            mstrResponse = "Recibido Correctamente"

        Catch ex As Exception
            mstrResponse = "Recibido pero con errores"
            MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
        bytesSent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mstrResponse)
        stream.Write(bytesSent, 0, bytesSent.Length)

    End Sub
```

Para enviar el socket en la aplicación cliente pues uso esto:

```
Protected Sub Send()
        Dim conexion As New SqlConnection(Cadena_Conexion)
        Dim a As Byte() = Nothing
        Dim Result As String = ""
        Dim sql As String = ""
        Try

            conexion.Open()

            sql = "SELECT H_1 FROM Persona WHERE H_TypeDocument_ID = '1' AND H_Document_ID = '1032494911'"

            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conexion)
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            If reader.Read Then
                a = reader.GetValue(0)
            End If
            reader.Close()
            cmd.Dispose()
            conexion.Dispose()

            Dim output As String = ""
            Dim serverIP As String = "localhost"
            Try
                ' Create a TcpClient.
                ' The client requires a TcpServer that is connected
                ' to the same address specified by the server and port
                ' combination.
                Dim port As Int32 = 60000
                'Dim port As Int32 = 13
                Dim client As New TcpClient(serverIP, port)

                ' Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a byte array.
                Dim data As Byte()
                data = a

                ' Get a client stream for reading and writing.
                ' Stream stream = client.GetStream();
                Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
                MsgBox("Tamaño enviado: " & data.Length)
                ' Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)

                output = "Sent: Se ha enviado los byte correctamente"
                MessageBox.Show(output)

                ' Buffer to store the response bytes.
                data = New [Byte](1800) {}

                ' String to store the response ASCII representation.
                Dim responseData As String = String.Empty

                ' Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
                Dim bytes As Int32 = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
                responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes)
                output = "Received: " + responseData
                MessageBox.Show(output)

                ' Close everything.
                stream.Close()
                client.Close()
            Catch e As ArgumentNullException
                output = "ArgumentNullException: " + e.ToString()
                MessageBox.Show(output)
            Catch e As SocketException
                output = "SocketException: " + e.ToString()
                MessageBox.Show(output)
            End Try

            Result = "Exito"
        Catch ex As Exception
            Result = "Error: " & ex.ToString
        End Try

    End Sub
```

¿Cómo se hace esto, cómo uso un web service asp.net para hacer traslado de información entre estas dos aplicaciones cómo lo hago con sockets?

Comment: Hola Fabian. Voto para cerrar tu pregunta como **muy amplia**. No aportas código que tengas (por ejemplo de los `sockets`) ni tus intentos de usar `web services`. Sin más informacion no podemos solucionar tu problema. Un saludo!

Comment: Estoy pidiendo información sobre cómo hacerlo, no tengo idea de cómo hacerlo, claro, tengo ejemplos de funciones que están en la web de microsoft :/ y los sockets igualmente, si es mucho problema, colocaré los códigos que tengo de los sockets

Comment: la cosa es que pedir esa informacion es otro tipo de preguna que se cerraría. es opinion personal... aqui las preguntas han de ser [concretas y comprobables](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Entonces no puedo preguntar cómo utilizar un web service como puente entre dos aplicaciones para transmisión de información entre ella?

Comment: Lee la documentacion al respecto, e intentalo. En la programacion es mucho intentar e investigar y no preguntar a la primera de cambio (no se tu situacion, solo hablo en general). Presentanos un codigo de tu intento de `web services` con tus dudas o con los errores que te salen para poder orientarte. Un saludo

Comment: @FabianMontoya. Echale un vistazo a este video, de repente te puede servir https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGmPQyRej4

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que te entiendo, básicamente lo que quieres es enviar información de una aplicación Web a una aplicación Windows o viceversa y actualmente lo haces con sockets, por lo visto tienes una consulta y esa consulta quieres que se muestre en una de las aplicaciones.

Lo que te recomiendo es que expongas esa consulta en un servicio ya sea WCF o ASMX, es decir toda a esa consulta debería ser un método o operación del servicio, luego en tu aplicación lo que haces es consumir el servicio con esa operación, claro considerando tu regla de negocio, es decir si la aplicación A realizo toda la regla de negocio debería hacer algún cambio a nivel de la base de datos para que se refleje el valor o resultado en la aplicación B, del mismo modo puede iniciar haciendo el cambio la aplicación B; todo eso hará que muestre algún resultado a nivel de aplicaciones.

Comment: Hola Hadson, ten en cuenta lo siguiente en las respuestas que se ofrece en [SOes](http://es.stackoverflow.com). Visita el Centro de Ayuda de [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)